# PHP form fields to an array

Tags: php, forms, post

The data is not being added

```
$user = array(); 
$user['First Name'] = $_POST['first']; 
$user['Last Name'] = $_POST['last'];
$user['Username'] = $_POST['username'];
$user['Password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: Use `$user['your_key']`. Remove `=`sign

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong.

You need to use these:

```
$user = array();

$user['First Name'] = $_POST['first'];
$user['Last Name'] = $_POST['last'];
$user['Username'] = $_POST['username'];
$user['Password'] = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: don't trust those $_POST values. Use htmlentities on them to mitigate cross site scripting. Also you have spaces in your array indexes. Instead of $user['First Name] it should be $user['FirstName']

Comment: You are right @JackAlbright . I just want to show how we cant o assign a data series.